# Use condition in a dataframe to replace values in another dataframe with nan

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

I have a dataframe that contains concentration values for a set of samples as follows:

| Sample | Ethanol | Acetone | Formaldehyde | Methane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| A | 30 | 23 | 20 | nan |
| A | 20 | 23 | nan | nan |
| A | nan | 20 | nan | nan |
| B | 21 | 46 | 87 | 54 |
| B | 23 | 74 | nan | 54 |
| B | 23 | 67 | nan | 53 |
| B | 23 | nan | nan | 33 |
| C | 23 | nan | nan | 66 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 88 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 90 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 88 |

I have second dataframe that contains the proportion of concentration values that are not missing in the first dataframe:

| Sample | Ethanol | Acetone | Formaldehyde | Methane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.75 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.25 |
| B | 1 | 0.75 | 0.25 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I would like to replace value in the first dataframe with nan when the condition in the second dataframe is 0.5 or less. Hence, the resulting dataframe would look like that below. Any help would be great!

| Sample | Ethanol | Acetone | Formaldehyde | Methane |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 | nan | nan |
| A | 30 | 23 | nan | nan |
| A | 20 | 23 | nan | nan |
| A | nan | 20 | nan | nan |
| B | 21 | 46 | nan | 54 |
| B | 23 | 74 | nan | 54 |
| B | 23 | 67 | nan | 53 |
| B | 23 | nan | nan | 33 |
| C | 23 | nan | nan | 66 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 88 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 90 |
| C | 22 | nan | nan | 88 |

Comment: First, what have you try so far? Next, can you give a result for a cell please and explain how to obtain the right value, please?

Comment: So far, I've only manage to generate the second dataframe from the first. I am not sure how to even start the second part...any keywords, places I can look for iteration over the the colunm and rows of a dataframe would be great!

Comment: If it wasn't clear, I would like to replace values in the first dataframe with nan when value in the second are equal to or below 0.5. So that would mean replacing values for Sample A + formaldehyde = nan, Sample B + formaldehyde = nan and sample A + methane = nan.

Comment: I've updated my original question so its slightly clearer.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it :) Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Is it what your are looking for:

```
>>> df2.set_index('Sample').mask(lambda x: x <= 0.5) \
       .mul(df1.set_index('Sample')).reset_index()

   Sample  Ethanol  Acetone  Formaldehyde  Methane
0       A     15.0    20.00           NaN      NaN
1       A     22.5    23.00           NaN      NaN
2       A     15.0    23.00           NaN      NaN
3       A      NaN    20.00           NaN      NaN
4       B     21.0    34.50           NaN     54.0
5       B     23.0    55.50           NaN     54.0
6       B     23.0    50.25           NaN     53.0
7       B     23.0      NaN           NaN     33.0
8       C     23.0      NaN           NaN     66.0
9       C     22.0      NaN           NaN     88.0
10      C     22.0      NaN           NaN     90.0
11      C     22.0      NaN           NaN     88.0
```

Comment: good answer, super.